Why are there multiple BIOS POSTs after choosing which drive to boot from?
I have a machine with three separate M.2 drives, with a version of Windows 10 installed on each. I run BitLocker on each drive.

When I boot up my machine I can choose which of the three installs I want to boot into.
I see the BIOS POST loading screen before choosing.
If I choose a different Windows install from the one I booted in last time (could be a week ago!), I have to go through the BIOS POST screen again.

Why is this, and is there a way around this?
Example:  Currently I'm inside Windows 1. I power off my machine. I turn it on again later:

BIOS POST -> Choose Windows Install -> I choose Windows 1 -> Windows loading screen -> Done

Conversely: Currently I'm inside Windows 1. I power off my machine. I turn it on again later:

BIOS POST -> Choose Windows Install -> I choose Windows 2 -> BIOS POST -> Windows loading screen -> Done


When you say you can choose, what are you choosing from? I would expect this to be the Windows Boot Manager, and all three Windows installs share the same Windows Boot Manager. If not, then what? Also, I assume you are UEFI booting Windows. If legacy BIOS booting, then include this in your question.

I'm choosing from 3 different versions of Windows. I assume I am UEFI booting too, but don't know!

It depends on the bootloader software that controls the dual/triple boot system.
There are actually several different ways to transfer control to the correct boot-drive (and set it as default for the next boots at the same time).
Some of these methods require that, to select a new default drive, the EFI is first updated to have the newly selected entry as "default" and then the last  step of the boot-process ("run default boot-entry" ) is re-triggered so it will now automatically execute the newly set entry.
This is usually NOT a full POST procedure (although it may visually look like one). It is just the "start the default boot-entry" last step.
And some EFI sytems always really do a full reboot including POST, because that is simply the way their EFI designer implemented the "re-trigger last step" feature.

It feels as slow as a normal POST procedure, but I guess it could be a partial one regardless. I assume it's Windows' own bootloader that I'm using? I just installed new drives and new versions through Windows itself and it showed up like that! :D Is there a better one that I can use that won't have these slower boots between versions?

When you boot up the previous boot option there is some configuration for fast boot up in UEFI bios , that is why you don't see post screen again , this option can be disabled
But when you change the boot option you experience full new boot up.

Won't that just slow everything down no matter what I was in previously?
